# How to default open an app by rosetta mode on Mac M1 after installation?

Tags: apple-m1

I developed a macOS application in Universal mode (with arm64 and x86_64), but some libraries are still in x86_64 architecture. Can I make my app run in x86_64 by default after installation? and how to do this? I know that the user has the option to run in rosetta mode in Application's Info, but I would like to know a way to set that by installation.

Comment: If you have Intel libraries that the app depends on, then surely the arm binary won't work? Why not just compile an Intel-only build until the libraries are available on arm64?

Comment: Because users can select to use arm64 mode to get more performance.

Comment: So it works on arm64, even with Intel dependencies?

Comment: Some features cannot use.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do that, but I think I can relaunch my application using arch -x86_64 to let my application in x86_64 mode.